# interface in c# getter and setter not working

Tags: c#, interface, getter-setter

I have an interface class **Position** with get and set methods.

Then I have classes **Objects1,Objects2,...** that extends **interface Position.**
And in the end I have class Scene which have List with getter and setter for this list. I am saving my Objects1, Objects2 in it.

Then I have a class Level that extends class Scene. There I created Objects1,Objects2,... and add them to the List.

When I get the first item from the List and I want to call that set function to set Position it says “Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable”. How to solve this?

```java
interface Position
    {
        public Vector2 PositionCords
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

```cs
class Scene
    {
        private List<Position> _Items;
        public Scene() 
        {
            _Items = new List<Position>();
        }

        public List<Position> SceneItems
        {
            get => _Items;
            set => _Items = value;
        }
    }
```

```cs
class Objects1 : Position
    {
        public Vector2 PositionCords
        {
            get;set; 
        }
    }
```

```cs
    class Level: Scene
    {
        private Scene _scene;
        private Objects1 _itemA;

        public Level()
        {
            _scene = new Scene();
            _itemA = new Objects1();
            _scene.SceneItems.Add(_itemA);
            _scene.SceneItems.Add(_itemA);

            //error
            _scene.SceneItems[0].PositionCords.X = 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This happens because `Vector2` is a struct, and `...PositionCords.X = 0` does not do what you'd expect it to do. I have linked your question to a duplication question that explains why this happens (and what to do about it) in more detail.

Comment: `Vector2` is a `struct`, so the methods return a copy from it and a property is like a method. So you cannot modify the struct directly, but you can re-assign/re-create it:

    `var firstScene = _scene.SceneItems.First(); firstScene.PositionCords = new Vector2(0, firstScene.PositionCords.Y);`